# How to use jQuery selector to filter jQuery isotope items case-insensitive (search)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm playing around with [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and want to implement an element search.  When the user types into a text box, I change the filter option like this:

```
var newFilter = '[data-myAttr*="' + $('#mySearchBox').val() + '"]';
$('#myIsotopeContainer').isotope({filter: newFilter});
```

I'm using jQuery's [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).  But it's case-sensitive, and I want to be case-*in*sensitive.  How can I accomplish this?

I've looked at other questions and Google results that suggest using `.filter(fn)`, but I don't have that much control with isotope.  I just give it a selector.

Comment: not sure where myAttr values come from but making them all lowercase and changing search value to lowercase seems to make sense

Comment: This is totally the easiest solution.  Post it as an answer and I'll at least upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lower case as protocol for all attributes and then change user input to lowercase

Answer (score 3):

From looking at Isotope's source, you should be able to pass a function, like this:

```
$('#myIsotopeContainer').isotope({ filter: function() {
        // case-insensitive pattern match:
        var pattern=new RegExp($('#mySearchBox').val(),'i');

        // test against 'data-myAttr':
        return pattern.test(this.attr('data-myAttr'));
    }
});
```

Isotope simply makes a `.filter()` call to do it's own filtering.  Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: +1 Adding a function for a filter works great.  I needed to filter based on an attribute of child.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give an answer that is related to this question for people like me who are doing this a little bit differently. I wanted to search any text in the whole element (or any children of the element), and not just an attribute. If you are using the :contains selector and want it to be case-insensitive, you should extend JQuery as outlined in [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278). I'm posting the code below for convenience:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
  {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});
```

Now you can use the JQuery like you would have using :contains('SomeString') but now use your new extended :containsi('SomeString')